# Nhibernate Dynamic Search With Comma

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate

I am using c# and Nhibernate to make a search in my database, I have to search for every term separate by comma, like: **foo, bar** - I have to search by any register that contains *foo* **OR** *bar*.

I am using the code below:

```
var terms = Term.Split(',');
        terms.Each(term =>
        {
            query = query.Where(x => x.Code.Contains(term) ||
                        x.Title.Contains(term) ||
                        x.Subtitle.Contains(term) ||
                        x.Type.Code.Contains(term) ||
                        x.Themes.Any(t => t.Title.Contains(term)) ||
                        x.Indicators.Any(i => i.Title.Contains(term)) ||
                        x.Indicators.Any(t => t.Type.Title.Contains(term)) ||
                        x.Indicators.Any(i => i.Sources.Any(s => s.Institution.Name.Contains(term))) ||
                        x.Indicators.Any(i => i.Sources.Any(s => s.Institution.Acronym.Contains(term))) ||
                        x.Indicators.Any(i => i.Sources.Any(s => s.Name.Contains(term))) ||
                        x.Indicators.Any(i => i.Sources.Any(s => s.Acronym.Contains(term))) ||
                        x.Indicators.Any(i => i.Sources.Any(s => s.Periodicity.Code.Contains(term))) ||
                        x.Indicators.Any(i => i.Sources.Any(s => s.Periods.Any(p => p.Date.Day.ToString().Contains(term) || p.Date.Month.ToString().Contains(term) || p.Date.Year.ToString().Contains(term)))) ||
                        x.Indicators.Any(i => i.Sources.Any(s => s.GeographicScope.Description.Contains(term))) ||
                        x.Indicators.Any(i => i.Sources.Any(s => s.AggregationLevel.Description.Contains(term))) ||
                        x.Indicators.Any(i => i.Keywords.Any(k => k.Description.Contains(term)))
                        );
        });
        return query;
```

But it's not work :c

Some sugestions?

Thx.

Answer (score 0):

NHibernate has to rewrite your Linq Query into an SQL Query in order to execute it against the DB. Your Linq Query is very complicated NHibernate might fail to translate it.

Without an error message it is very hard to guess what exactly goes wrong.